# ActiveRecord parse string to datetime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

If I pass a `String` into `Datetime` column while creating new AR object, it will be automatically parse:

```
1.9.2p290 :011 > Movie.new(:release_date=>"21-Nov-1990")
 => #<Movie id: nil, release_date: "1990-11-21 00:00:00", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

How does `Rails`, or `ActiveRecord`, do this magic? Which method does it use?

Comment: I also realize that the `Date` column behave the same way when I pass a string to it. I found that there is a `cast_value(value)` method in `rails/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/date.rb` (in face there are many `cast_value(value)` methods for each Type in active model) that call `fast_string_to_date(value)` or `fallback_string_to_date(value)` methods if the value is String. I guess the `cast_value` get called by ActiveModel before it save the record.

Comment: Anyone knows where this behaviour is documented? I could not find it, may have missing something actually, I am currently going through rails code directly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rails adds a [`to_date`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_date) method to `String`. Its source is simple:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/conversions.rb, line 42
def to_date
  return nil if self.blank?
  ::Date.new(*::Date._parse(self, false).values_at(:year, :mon, :mday))
end
```

`Date._parse` is native to Ruby (the same method is called by `Date.parse`) and it's [where the real work is done](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/_parse/class).

It first uses a regular expression to remove extraneous symbols from the string, then passes it to other methods like `_parse_eu`, `_parse_iso`, `_parse_dot` and so on. Each of these uses its own regular expressions and other methods to see if it's a date that it understands and extract the meaningful information from it. Once one of them "works" (i.e. returns true), the rest are skipped. Finally, back in `_parse`, the extracted information is used to build a date and time, doing a little more work to figure out things like checking for the day of the week and whether a year value of "12" should mean 1912 or 2012.

The docs call this a heuristic method, which could be taken to mean it throws a bunch of possibilities at the wall to see what sticks. It's pretty poorly-documented but works remarkably well.

Answer (score 2):

There's also `to_datetime` if you need the time.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `Date.strptime(str)`.

Comment: `strptime` has to know the date format otherwise it would use its default format. But AR can magically parse dates in several formats.

Comment: Be sure you're testing all the date formats that a user might present. They are not always deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

As other comments and the documentation suggests, [String#to_datetime](https://apidock.com/rails/String/to_datetime) "Converts a string to a DateTime value.":

```
"1-1-2012".to_datetime            # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 +0000 
"01/01/2012 23:59:59".to_datetime # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012 23:59:59 +0000 
"2012-12-13 12:50".to_datetime    # => Thu, 13 Dec 2012 12:50:00 +0000 
"12/13/2012".to_datetime          # => ArgumentError: invalid date
```