# ActiveRecord with different Date/Time format

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, activerecord

We have an application where user sets his/her preferred date/time format. User is expected to enter `datetime` in configured format across the application. Now the problem is for few formats the `datetime` is parsed wrongly while `create/update` `ActiveRecord`.

For example user has set date/time format in `hh:mm dd/MM/yyyy`. Now if user enters `17:00 04/05/2012` it parses it as `5 PM 5 Apr, 2012` where it should be `5 PM 4 May, 2012`

```
1.8.7 :004 > a = Article.create!(:name => 'a1', :published_at => '17:00 04/05/2012')
 => #<Article id: 2, name: "a1", published_at: "2012-04-05 17:00:00", created_at: "2012-04-16 13:54:36", updated_at: "2012-04-16 13:54:36">
```

I understand that ruby/rails has predefined set of formats against which the date/time string is evaluated and if matches any format in sequence it parses given string with that format.

Another example

```
1.8.7 :006 > a = Article.create!(:name => 'a1', :published_at => '17:00 15/12/2012')
 => #<Article id: 4, name: "a1", published_at: nil, created_at: "2012-04-16 13:55:43", updated_at: "2012-04-16 13:55:43">
```

Here user entered `15 December, 2012` which was parsed to `nil`

Someone has already asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2529990) and on [ruby-forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/57923) but the solution is not applicable in my case as I cannot configure a single datetime format across the application as each user will have his own preferred datetime format.

Now to work with multiple `datetime` format, I am planning to manipulate it before the `params` is passed to the `ActiveRecord`. So the steps would like

1. Read `datetime` from `params` map
2. Parse it with user's preferred datetime format
3. Format `datetime` to the default format used by `ActiveRecord`
4. Replace current `datetime` in `params` with re-formatted datetime

Here is a snippet of the controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :format_date_time, :only => [:create, :update]
  ...
  ...
  private
    def format_date_time
      datetime = params[:datetime]
      params[:datetime] = DateTime.strptime(datetime, pref_date_time_format).strftime('%c')
    end
end
```

Would anyone please verify if it is right approach or not? I would be appreciable if someone suggests better ways to accomplish this.

Thanks,
Amit Patel

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9725374/517483) is nice explanation how `string` is automatically converted to `date` in `ActiveRecord`

Comment: Draiken has responded on [ruby-forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4085912) to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the approach I mentioned. If anyone has better way please keep sharing.

Thanks, Amit Patel